# Какую библиотеку лучше использовать в РНР 5.3 для работы с видео?

Tags: php, видео

Пытаюсь использовать либу для работы с видео php_ffmpeg.dll, у меня php 5.3.4 но apache выдает ошибку

> PHP Startup: ffmpeg: Unable to initialize module
> Module compiled with module API=20060613
> PHP compiled with module API=20090626
> These options need to match

Я так понял, данная либа скомпилена только под РНР 5.2. Вопрос, есть ли подобные библиотеки под мою версию РНР, и вообще, что можно сделать, чтобы либа работала, кроме установки более старых версий РНР?

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно из РНР работать с видео.
РНР - это Hypertext Preprocessor, а не Home Video Entertainment

Вся работа РНР с видеофалом должна сводиться к приему файла, первичной проверке, и **постановке задания в очередь конвертации.**

А механизм очередей уже в фоновом режиме пусть конвертирует, и безо всякого РНР, прямым обращением к консольному ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Версия ffmpeg очень старая.

1. Можно искать более новую (судя по последней дате обновления исходников, это мало реально).
2. Собрать ffmpeg из исходников для текущей версии PHP.

Comment: Если ffmpeg очень старая, то почему бы вам не предложить альтернативу?

Answer (score 0):

avi2flv конвертер, а так вроде больше ничего и нету